# How Do You Say "I read it wrong" in Japanese?

Tags: expressions, english-to-japanese

How Do You Say "I read it wrong" in Japanese?

Is there such a word like 読み間違え or something like that in Japanese?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The word for it is 読み間違える, as you hinted at. Some other words that seem to be more limited to metaphorical instances of reading people or situations include 読{よ}み誤{あやま}る ("misread the political picture" 政治情勢を読み誤る) as well as 見誤{みあやま}る ("misread a signal," or 合図［信号・サイン］を見誤る)

These examples and others can be seen [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=misread&ref=sa).